# Update Facebook App Permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have a Facebook app and would like to change the permissions on it. These were straightforward to set when I created the app, but when I login to the app and go through the settings, I can't find any mention of permissions. Where do I go to update the permissions on an existing app?

Comment: belongs with the http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ community.

Comment: I struggled for a long time with that !

So here can be a tip : the Permissions in your FB App settings seems to do nothing. You need to ask them in the 'scope' parameter when you ask for the user to login !!

Exemple : 
 FB.login(function (response) {
      if(response.authResponse)
         // OK
   }, { scope: 'publish_stream, email, user_likes, user_birthday, friends_birthday, publish_actions' });

Comment: well this previous comment is definitely ugly, but I can't leave an answer ?

Comment: I suggest this question be re-opened.  It is actually about app development, and using the facebook JavaScript API correctly.  The response from Chris above answers it well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If you are user using another app**: you cannot modify existing permissions. The best you can do is deauthorize the app.

**If you are the owner of the app, and you want to ask for additional permissions**: then you simply need to redirect your present users to the app authorization link requesting them to authorize the new permissions.

This assumes that you are referring to the API permissions. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: I am the owner of the app and would like to request additional permissions. It's currently in development--so I'm the only user. What I can't find is the place to specify which permissions I'd like to ask for--where in the app settings I can change this.

Comment: I answered my own question (sorry!) the permissions are part of the request, not something set in the app itself. For posterity, I'm using the ruby Devise gem with Omniauth.